# kitchen openstack steps/example

Tags: chef-infra, openstack, test-kitchen

I am trying to make it work the tool test kitchen with kitchen-openstack to perform some integration/functional test of some Chef recipes we have.

But I cannot get it work :(
I have a .kitchen.yml with following content:

```
driver:
  name: openstack
  openstack_username: test
  openstack_api_key: test
  openstack_auth_url: http://<openstackServerIp>:35357/v2.0/
  require_chef_omnibus: latest
  image_ref: CentOS-6.5-Template
  flavor_ref: cloud.tiny
  openstack_tenant: test

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: centos-6.5

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[myTestChef::default]
```

What I receive til now when I do kitchen create default-centos-65 is:

```
Message: Expected([200, 204]) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)
  response => #<Excon::Response:0x00000001eed698 @data={:body=>"{\"error\": {\"message\": \"get_version_v2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'\", \"code\": 400, \"title\": \"Bad Request\"}}", :headers=>{"Vary"=>"X-Auth-Token", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Content-Length"=>"121", "Date"=>"Mon, 05 May 2014 18:02:15 GMT"}, :status=>400, :remote_ip=>"<openstackServerIp>", :local_port=>34592, :local_address=>"192.168.10.32"}, @body="{\"error\": {\"message\": \"get_version_v2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'\", \"code\": 400, \"title\": \"Bad Request\"}}", @headers={"Vary"=>"X-Auth-Token", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Content-Length"=>"121", "Date"=>"Mon, 05 May 2014 18:02:15 GMT"}, @status=400, @remote_ip="<openstackServerIp>", @local_port=34592, @local_address="192.168.10.32">
```

When I run kitchen list, I get:

```
Instance           Driver     Provisioner  Last Action
default-centos-65  Openstack  ChefSolo     <Not Created>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody share some steps or examples how to set it up?

I am running this from a VM created in the same project of OpenStack.

Comment: Please format your code in the future

Comment: Sorry, I dont know very well how to use this about formats, I am brand new posting question here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I have to specify also the:

- server_name: `<VMName to create>`
- network_ref: `<the name of the network where the VM will be created>`
- public_key_path: `/home/<some local user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- private_key_path: `/home/<some local user>/.ssh/id_rsa`
- username: `<user to login into the VM that will be created>`

The *public_key_path* and *private_key_path* must be related with the *autorized_key* that will have the virtual machine to be created.

These last 3 SSH values are needed so Kitchen can connect into the created virtual machine so it can apply the chef recipes there.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get from OpenStack:

> "get_version_v2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'\"

This is because of the authentication URL. I had the same problem while using libcloud to connect to the OpenStack API.

What I was trying:

```
http://localhost:5000/v2.0/
```

The solution:

```
http://localhost:5000/
http://localhost:5000/v2.0/tokens/
```

Source: [Connecting to the OpenStack installation](http://ci.apache.org/projects/libcloud/docs/compute/drivers/openstack.html#connecting-to-the-openstack-installation)